# JS - how to replace &nbsp; in regex for links

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a regex that replaces the link from the moment http to the occurrence of certain characters in `[]`, I would like to add `&nbsp;` to these characters - that is to replace the string with the occurrence of certain characters or a hard space:

`"https://test.pl'".replace(/https?:\/\/[^ "'><]+/g," ")`

Works fine for the characters mentioned in `[]`, I don't know how to add here `&nbsp`;

Comment: Do you mean `.replace(/https?:\/\/(?:&nbsp;|[^ "'><])+/g," ")`?

Comment: does not work e.g. for the 'character, it will return everything after it:
`"https://test.pl'test".replace(/https?:\/\/(?:&nbsp;|[^ "'><])+/g," ")`

returns nothing for a hard space:
`"https://test.pl&nbsp;test".replace(/https?:\/\/(?:&nbsp;|[^ "'><])+/g," ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
.replace(/https?:\/\/.*?(?:&nbsp;|[ '"><]|$)/g," ")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OiD22A/2).

*Details*:

- `https?:\/\/` - `http://` or `https://`
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?:&nbsp;|[ '"><]|$)` - one of the following:

  - `&nbsp;` - `&nbsp;` char sequence
  - `|` - or
  - `[ "'><]` - a space, `"`, `'`, `>` or `<` char
  - `|` - or
  - `$` - end of string.

JavaScript demo:

```js
const texts = ["https://test.pl&nbsp;test","https://test.pl'test"];
const re = /https?:\/\/.*?(?:&nbsp;|[ '"><]|$)/g;
for (const s of texts) {
  console.log(s, '=>', s.replace(re, " "));
}
```

Comment: does not work e.g. for the `'` character, it will return everything after it: `"https://test.pl'test".replace(/https?:\/\/(?:&nbsp;|[^ "'><])+/g," ")` 

for hard space returns nothing: 
`"https://test.pl&nbsp;test".replace(/https?:\/\/(?:&nbsp;|[^ "'><])+/g," ")`

Comment: @piker If you need to match `'`, remove it from the negated character class - `.replace(/https?:\/\/(?:&nbsp;|[^ "><])+/g," ")`. `"https://test.pl&nbsp;test".replace(/https?:\/\/(?:&nbsp;|[^ "'><])+/g," ")` returns a space, so "hard space" is matched alright.

Comment: but I want the hard space to work like `'`. I want the link to be removed & nbsp - that is, treated as a normal string.

Comment: @piker Then just remove `'` from your regex, see `/https?:\/\/[^ "><]+/g` at https://regex101.com/r/OiD22A/1

Comment: I can't remove this character - because it works fine, like any other character added for []. I want this to work for &nbsp; that is, replaced with "" from the occurrence of: https or http until the occurrence of the character mentioned in [] or &nbsp;

Comment: @piker "it works fine",  so what is the problem? Do not use words like "add to regex", "add for brackets". Explain the rules: what do you want to do? Remove one or more chars... or a sequence of chars... and provide a couple of examples with expected outputs.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I would like it to replace the given string by the user - from the occurrence from http or https to the occurrence of certain characters: `" '> <`or just `&nbsp;`- and now I cannot add this` &nbsp;` to strings, so I want e.g.
`"https: //test.pl&nbsp; test" .replace (/ https?: \ / \ / (?: & nbsp; | [^ "'> <]) + / g," ")` returned the test.


Just like for
`"https: //test.pl'test" .replace (/ https?: \ / \ / (?: & nbsp; | [^ "'> <]) + / g," ")` return test

Comment: @piker Ok, see the updated solution.

Comment: Thank you very much - it is already working. And what to do to leave the given character, i.e. for your solution, it will return me:
&nbsp;test
'test

Comment: @piker Then turn the non-capturing group into a positive lookahead: `https?:\/\/.*?(?=&nbsp;|[ '"><]|$)`